# On a particular case of Dirichlet series

Tags: power-series, dirichlet-series, divergent-series, theta-series

I've this series:

$$ \sum_{\ell = 1}^{+ \infty} e^{-t \ \ell^2} \sin{(k\ell)} = f(k, t) $$

where $ t \in [0,\infty]$  ,  $ k \in [0,2\pi] $.

I need the limit of series like an analytic function of $ k $ and $ \ell $ : $ f( k , \ell)$ .

I tried to transform the sine to exponential but without result.
This series is quite similar to the third theta Jacobi elliptic function.

For details check this link: http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_567.htm pag $\sim $ 575

My question is: how can I sum that series? Is there some good method to get a result (no matter in terms of what kind of functions)?

Comment: what is the function f(k,t), how to sum the series?

Comment: How is this related to Dirichlet series?

Comment: this series is like the first formula  (1) of the first page of this book: http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/Dirichlet%20Series%20de%20Hardy.pdf   , @მამუკაჯიბლაძე